# How do I do simple flat link to .php file redirect?

Tags: .htaccess

My current .htaccess file is as

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

This is at the directory level, I do not want to have a site-wide .htaccess.

I can redirect ../file.html to ../file.php but I am not able to do it for ../file -> ../file.php

My URL would be www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/file/ The file that should be run is www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/file.php But I want this rule to work only under sub2. So the rule will be included in the .htaccess at sub2

What exactly I need to change on this code to be able to do that?

More specifically, why is this not working?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as I want it to work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your existing rule to this to work under `/sub1/sub2/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub1/sub2/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like to have it ../file/ showing ../file.php so there will not be any .html, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. What exact URL do you want to show in browser and how should it be handled internally?

Comment: My URL would be www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/file/
The file that should be run is www.domain.com/sub1/sub2/file.php
But I want this rule to work only under sub2. So the rule will be included in the .htaccess at sub2

Comment: ok that information should have been in question. Anyway check updated code for `/sub1/sub2/.htaccess`

Comment: Should we remove the part with the .html part as well?

Comment: Yes comment out your `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]` rule.